# CKeditor trigger click externally -switch between source and wysiwyg - js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to trigger click externally
first click - source
then back to wysiwyg mode

Comment: show us your snipped code

Comment: CKEDITOR.instances[textareaName].execCommand( 'source' ); CKEDITOR.instances[textareaName].execCommand( 'wysiwyg' );